# Tkinter root stops updating after image shown

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to show an image multiple times after several button presses, though once I've pressed the button once, and altered the entry input, it no longer updates.

Code:

```
 import tkinter as tk 
 import qrcode 
 from PIL import ImageTk,Image
 root = tk.Tk() 
 root.geometry('300x300')
 root.resizable(False,False)
 root.title('QR-Code Maker')

 def create_qrcode(data:str):
     qrc = qrcode.make(data,box_size=10)
     return qrc

 def buttoncallback(entry):
     data_for_qrcode = entry.get()
     qrc = create_qrcode(data_for_qrcode)
     qrc.save('QRCODE.PNG')

     img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('QRCODE.PNG'))
 
     panel = tk.Label(root,image=img)
     panel.pack(side='bottom',fill='both',expand='yes')
 
     root.mainloop()

 def main():
     entry = tk.Entry(root)
     entry.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)
 
     button = tk.Button(root,text='Genereer QR',command=lambda:buttoncallback(entry))
     button.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)
     root.mainloop()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

I'm sure I've missed something incredibly obvious, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out

Comment: Every time you create a new image, you add it to the bottom of the window - which is of a fixed size.  I'm sure all of the images are actually being created, they're just being pushed off the bottom of the window, where you can't see them.  You either need to delete the previous image when you create the new one, or have a single Label from the very start that you simply assign the new image to.

Comment: I've made the root resizable, the root now expands but isn't showing any image.

Comment: You need to save a reference to the image somewhere for as long as it's being displayed, to keep it from being garbage-collected.  `panel.img = img` would be one approach.

Comment: How would I go about deleting the previous QR code and putting the new one in the previous' place?

Comment: This looks like a duplciate of [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091)

Comment: @BryanOakley Sounds right...we really ought to have something like a 'sticky' for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two calls to `root.mainloop()` - you should only have one (specifically, the one in `main()`). Remove the call to `root.mainloop()` from `buttoncallback()`

```
 def buttoncallback(entry):
     data_for_qrcode = entry.get()
     qrc = create_qrcode(data_for_qrcode)
     qrc.save('QRCODE.PNG')

     img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('QRCODE.PNG'))
 
     panel = tk.Label(root,image=img)
     panel.pack(side='bottom',fill='both',expand='yes')
 
     # root.mainloop()  <-- remove this
```

Comment: I've tried that, but then it won't show on even the first time. How do I get it to update without a root.mainloop?

Comment: You can call `root.update_idletasks()` to refresh the UI, but I suspect @jasonharper is correct about what's happening to your images